# ViewModel. Set data

Tags: android, viewmodel

I have two fragments. In the first list of cards. When you click on the card, the second fragment is opened with a full description. I put in the bundle tag that I installed in the adapter. In the second fragment I get it and I need to set data by tag.

In the onChanged method, I write model.setVerse ((List ) data); but nothing happens.

At first I tried to do tvTitle.setText(data.getTitle) but nothing happened either.

viewModel

```
 public class DataViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

LiveData<Data> currentVerse;

public DataViewModel(@NonNull Application application, final int verseId) {
    super(application);
    int verseId1 = verseId;
    DataRepository repository = new DataRepository(application);
    currentVerse = repository.getById(verseId);

}

public LiveData<Data> getById() {
    return currentVerse;
}
public void setVerse(List<Data> data) {
    this.currentVerse= (LiveData<Data>) data;

}


public static class ModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

    @NonNull
    private final Application application;
    private final int verseId;
    private final DataRepository repository;

    public ModelFactory(@NonNull Application application, int id) {
        super();
        this.application = application;
        this.verseId = id;
        repository = new DataRepository(application);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass == DataViewModel.class) {
            return (T) new DataViewModel(application, verseId);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

fragment

```
 public class DataFragment extends Fragment {
private int verseId;
private static final String KEY_VERSE_ID = "KEY_VERSE_ID";
public TextView tvTitle;

public DataFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootViewRead = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, 
false);
    Toolbar toolbar = rootViewRead.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    tvTitle = (TextView) rootViewRead.findViewById(R.id.text);

    DataViewModel.ModelFactory factory = new DataViewModel.ModelFactory(
            getActivity().getApplication(), 
 getArguments().getInt(KEY_VERSE_ID));

    final DataViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(DataViewModel.class);
    model.getById().observe(this, new Observer<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Data data) {
            model.setVerse((List<Data>) data);


        }
    });

    return rootViewRead;
}

public static DataFragment forData(int verseId) {
    DataFragment fragment = new DataFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_VERSE_ID, verseId);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

if necessary, I will add the dao and repository classes

Answer (score 1):

Below is the part that you need to modify to set the value of LiveData:

```
LiveData<<List>Data>> currentVerse;

public void setVerse(List<Data> data) {
    this.currentVerse.setValue(data);

}
```

For more details [click here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#update_livedata_objects)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: unfortunately not working. I replaced LiveData with MutableLiveData in the ViewModel as specified in the documentation, it still did not help